# UIViewController remove from superview after receiving nsnotification

Tags: uiviewcontroller, nsnotifications

i'm trying to remove a UIViewController from the superview after receiving a notification but it doesn't work.

in my appDelegate i do something like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{    
NSLog(@"applicationDidFinishLaunching");
[window addSubview:tabBar.view];
splash = [[SplashViewController alloc] init]; <-- this i want to remove
[window addSubview:splash.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible]; }
```

in the SplashViewController i register the view to receive NSNotifications like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(fadeScreen:) name:@"CloseSplashScreen" object:nil];
```

the SplashViewController appears right after the Default.png and should fade smoothly after some data is parsed...

in my TableViewControler i want to send the notification in the viewWillAppear method but it doesn't work.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CloseSplashScreen" object:self];}
```

the method gets called but the view is not removed from the superview. i tried to put the postNotification in - (void)viewDidLoad  but the method doesn't get called...

any ideas why this is not working? thank you in advance

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Im dealing with a similar issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you are trying to implement some sort of splash screen, consider using a UINavigationController to present the splash. What you are doing is adding a view controllers view as a subview of UIWindow yet no one is managing your view controller. This is not how you should be doing things.

UIWindow has the method setRootViewController which should be in your appDelegate. That way you can push your Splash Controller, and after a certain interval push the first viewController of the app.

As a sidenote, I understand that some developers use splash screens as a means of reinforcing brand identity. That being said, consider [Apples Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/StartingStopping.html):

> As much as possible, avoid displaying a splash screen or other startup
>   experience. It’s best when users can begin using your app immediately.